# Deep population not working with embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have three documents as below:

```
 var TrackAudioSchema = new Schema({
        track_id: {
          type: Number,
        },
            track_path:{
                type:String,
                required:'Please upload audio track'
            }
      });
    mongoose.model('TrackAudio', TrackAudioSchema);

    var trackSchema = new Schema({
                title: {
                    type: String,
                    trim:true,
                    required:'Please fill track title'
                 },
                 version : {
                    type: String,
                    trim: true,
                    default: ''
                 },
                 trackpath:{
                    type: Schema.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'TrackAudio'
                },
        });

    var AlbumSchema = new Schema({
      language: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        tracks:[trackSchema],
        user: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
)};

AlbumSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);
mongoose.model('Album', AlbumSchema);
```

but when I try to populate `trackpath` from `trackSchema` using the below query,  it doesn't populate:

```
Album.findById(albumId)
         .populate('user','name label').
         deepPopulate('tracks.trackpath').
         exec(function(err, albumdetail) {

         }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing:

```
mongoose.model('Track', TrackSchema);
```